# Appending array values to csv

Tags: node.js, json, csv

I would like to take some output and append the output to a csv

This is the code I have so far:

```
async function writeData() {
    const csv = require('csv-parser')
    const results = [];
    fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\testingclean.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data',(data)=> results.push(data))
        .on('end', async () => {
            const cookieJar = await getCookieJar();
            const promises = [];
            results.forEach((data) => {
                promises.push(boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar,data.id));
            })
            try {
                const fighters = await Promise.all(promises);
                fighters.forEach((fighter)=>{
                    boxer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fighter.output));
                    fs.appendFile('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\newtest.csv',boxer, (err) => {
                        if (err) console.error('Could not append data to csv');
                        console.log('Data successfully appended');
                    })
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        })
};
try {
    writeData();
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in writeData: " + error);
}
```

However running this code does not produce the desired csv output.

I am specifically writing to csv because I have read that I cannot append to a json (would ideally want to write data to a json)

Comment: Use a try-catch block to catch the promise rejection error. Then update the answer with specific error. Create the try-catch inside `end` event callback.

Comment: fs.createReadStream needs catch block. or on('error', ()=>{}) . 
check this out https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-fs-create-read-stream/

Comment: @Dijkstra edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have anything writen to the CSV file, you should close it explicitly at the end of your program :

```
var readsteam = fs.createReadStream();
...
readStream.destroy();
```

Not sure but this should be the full code :

```
async function writeData() {
    const csv = require('csv-parser')
    const results = [];
    var readsteam = fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\testingclean.csv');
    readsteam
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data',(data)=> results.push(data))
        .on('end', async () => {
            const cookieJar = await getCookieJar();
            const promises = [];
            results.forEach((data) => {
                promises.push(boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar,data.id));
            })
            try {
                const fighters = await Promise.all(promises);
                fighters.forEach((fighter)=>{
                    boxer = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fighter.output));
                    fs.appendFile('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\newtest.csv',boxer, (err) => {
                        if (err) console.error('Could not append data to csv');
                        console.log('Data successfully appended');
                    })
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    readsteam.destroy();
};
try {
    writeData();
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in writeData: " + error);
}
```

Comment: should this appear after  the line promises.push or after fs.appendFile